# iOS VPN on Demand rules

Tags: swift, xcode, vpn, nevpnmanager

I want to create a onDemandRule for VPN connnection in ios

Requirement is as follows.

If Both cellular and wifi is available
and wifi ssid = "ABC"
than only VPN will run otherwise it should stop.

I have tried following OnDemandRule

```
             let onDemandRule = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
            onDemandRule.interfaceTypeMatch = .wiFi
            onDemandRule.ssidMatch = ["ABC"]

            let onDemandRule1 = NEOnDemandRuleConnect()
            onDemandRule1.interfaceTypeMatch = .cellular                
            self.vpnManager.isOnDemandEnabled = true

            let onDemandRule2 = NEOnDemandRuleDisconnect()
            onDemandRule2.interfaceTypeMatch = .any

            self.vpnManager.onDemandRules = [onDemandRule, onDemandRule1, onDemandRule2]
```

It works as soon as i connect to a wifi named ABC

But it doesn't disconnect if i switch off cellular data.
Can someone please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the rules like a set of firewall rules, `NEVPNManager` goes through the list of rules and the first rule that applies is followed. In your example when you would switch off cellular data it will evaluate rule 1: wifi + SSID "ABC". If that rules satisfies i.e. you are connected to WiFi SSID "ABC", the vpn will be connected. If not, `NEVPNManager` will go through the next rule.

If you switch off cellular, the first rule still applies. (You can still have a WiFi connection). `NEVPNManager` can't differentiate between cellular on/off. It can only differentiate between which interface is used: cellular, WiFi or any.

Comment: Thanks Marcel.. Any idea how can i manage that scenario? Means as soon as cellular data is switched off VPN should stop? any other way other than onDemand rule?

Comment: The VPNManager doesn't care wether the radio is on or not, only if it's the primary interface. In the Configuration Profile reference you can find what your possibilities are https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf